# Anywhere to find historical float shares (or restricted shares) of US stocks?

Tags: historical-data, fundamentals

I'm trying to collect the historical stock float data, but can't find it nowhere.  We can easily find historical quarterly shares outstanding data in sec edgar, and we know that floating stock = outstanding shares - restricted shares.  However, I can't find historical restricted shares data either.  Anyone know somewhere providing that?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg has float information, but it's imperfect.  I imagine other vendors offer the same, but the reality is this sort of thing is typically done at the report level by hand (ie, analysts go through financial reports to determine % of shares held by 'insiders' (definition varies)).  I'd be highly skeptical of any free source claiming to offer this information.